# Populate field with result from a function?

Tags: python, arcpy

I want to make a new column in every shapefile using for loop and populate that column using a function.

```
#the function

def find_folder(fn, k=-2):
    return os.path.split(fn)[0].split(os.sep)[k]
```

I tried:

```
fi = path
d = defaultdict(list)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fi):
    for shapefile in files:
        if shapefile.endswith('.shp'):
            arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(root,shapefile), "field_Tmp", "LONG")
            #here fill new field with 'find_folder(shapefile)' <---- How to do this?   
           d[os.path.basename(shapefile)].append(os.path.join(root,shapefile))
```

**Useful notes:**

When the function is used, ex.

```
find_folder(shapefile)
```

it will give always the part of path that has a code. 1873, 8383, etc

Therefore, the `field_Tmp` will be populated with a number like that in every iteration for every shapefile found in the loop.

For people who know pandas it would be like this:

```
df = geopandas.read_file(shpfile).assign(field_Tmp = find_folder(shapefile))
```

## Edit

Finally I am using the dictionary for the merge of all the shapefiles.

```
for cat, lst in d.items():
        if cat.endswith('.shp'):
            pd.concat(lst,sort = True).to_file(folder/cat)
```

Comment: Comment on you EDIT: I dont know exactly what you are doing. But you already have checked it the file is ending with shape so no need to do that again. Cant you use a list? `shapelist = []`  then `shapelist.append(os.path.join(root,shapefile)` above add field line? Then merge: `arcpy.Merge....(shapelist)`

Comment: This causes `ERROR 000468: Input shape types are not equal ` . I have made https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305220/error-000468-input-shape-types-are-not-equal this detailed question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Field Calculator or [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to fill the column with values.

```
arcpy.AddField...
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(os.path.join(root,shapefile), "field_Tmp") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = find_folder(shapefile)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

(I have not tried the function or the rest of your code.)

Comment: Yes it is your function that is causing the error.

Comment: It needed the os.path.join

Comment: About the `d[os.path.basename(shapefile)].append(os.path.join(root,shapefile))` line, where should I put it in order to work in your answer?

Comment: Before add field, between add field and the cursor or after the cursor. It does not matter. What are you going to use the Dictionary for?

Comment: It does matter I think, I am doing a merge of all the shapefiles later so having the new field you just made after the concatenation is important. I added the last part  of code with the merge I was referring to, so you can tell me for sure where I should put that line with the dictionary.